# How to make Symfony faster

Tags: php, performance, optimization, symfony-1.4

My symfony projects work veeery slow, between 4 and 8 seconds per page 
(I'm working in dev environment). I've tried to use PHP APC (with it, it works slower), I've tried to optimize my code, I`ve tried to explore standard symfony library, etc. But nothig helped me.

P.S. I have a good hardware, i`m sure that problem isn't in it.

Comment: I don't think the problem is symfony being so much slow, since it wouldn't have been the respectable framework it is today. The issue is not that for sure. Have you profiled your app?

Comment: not yet, Damien, i`m going to do it now

Comment: Are you working on Windows? I've found the Win environment quite slow with symfony, historically anyway.

Comment: Yes, my OS is Windows, but my colleague uses Windows too, and his symfony projects work quite fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find where your bottle neck is in your application.

Most likely, this won't be a Symfony issue, but something you have done or a way you have done it.

Install XDebug, profile your application, then analyze the results to figure out what is taking all the relative time to compute. 
You will probably see something taking like 98% of the relative time, and it will probably be something obscure like a timeout request etc.

Comment: Thanks, bro, i`ll try to follow your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Use the profiler to find the bottleneck. There is no way we can determine which part of your application is slow.

You will have to run some benchmark yourself by logging the time at key execution points to drill down into the code until you find the place of the slowness.

Comment: Thank you, I'll start debugging immediately.